# C++11 compiler error when using decltype(var) followed by internal type of "var"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, compiler-errors, decltype

I'm using Visual C++ 2010, and here's my code snippet:

```
std::set<int> s;
decltype(s)::value_type param = 0;
```

I got the following error message, anyone can help me?

```
> error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'param'
```

Comment: It's a compiler bug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a Visual Studio bug that was raised last year on Connect. It is [issue 757545 ("Cannot use decltype before scope operator")](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757545/cannot-use-decltype-before-scope-operator).

The issue has a workaround listed alongside it that is effectively the same as @iammillind's, except it uses `std::identity` that was removed from `<functional>` shortly prior to the publication of C++11, for whatever reason. ([`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) with one template parameter is equivalent; [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) is the same in some cases.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yep should do, especially as the workaround being posted on Connect implies VS supports it. I only wish the workaround submitter had made a note of it; [surprise, surprise, MSDN doesn't care.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee391705.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I see that with g++ 4.7.2 version, the code compiles fine. So it could be a **compiler bug** in MSVS.
For time being you can try below trick:

```
#ifdef COMPILER_BUG_STILL_THERE
template<typename T> struct Get { typedef T type; };
#define DECLTYPE(VAR) Get<decltype(VAR)>::type
#else
#define DECLTYPE(VAR) decltype(VAR)
#endif
```

Use it as:

```
DECLTYPE(s)::value_type param = 0;
```

*Disclaimer*: Ofcourse with this trick, you may have to use `typename` when inside templates. For that you can have 1 more macro such as `#define TDECLTYPE(VAR) typename DECLTYPE(VAR)`